# Compile Python embed C library on Windows, got error C2371: 'pid_t' : redefinition; different basic types

Tags: python, c++, windows, ace

I searched on google, this issue caused by a bug of ACE, here's the bug link:
http://bugzilla.dre.vanderbilt.edu/show_bug.cgi?id=3190

In ACE head file os_types.h, define pid_t as

```
#if defined (ACE_WIN32) && !defined(__MINGW32__)
   typedef long pid_t;
#elif defined (ACE_PSOS) && (!defined (ACE_PSOSIM) && defined (ACE_PSOS_CANT_USE_SYS_TYPES))
#  if defined (ACE_PSOS_DIAB_PPC)
#    define ACE_INVALID_PID ((pid_t) ~0)
#  else /* !defined (ACE_PSOS_DIAB_PPC) */
     typedef long pid_t;
#  endif /* defined (ACE_PSOS_DIAB_PPC) */
   typedef char* caddr_t;
#endif /* ACE_PSOS_CANT_USE_SYS_TYPES */
```

In Python head file pyconfig.h, define pid_t as

```
#endif /* MS_WIN32 && !MS_WIN64 */
typedef int pid_t;
```

There's no such #ifdef
So there must be an redefinition error.

My problem is that I can not change the head file os_types in ACE library for some reasons.

Is there any other workaround except modify these two head files?

I add some code like this:

```
#ifndef __MINGW32__
#define __MINGW32__
#endif
```

And some errors related to ACE occurred.

Comment: Check if any of the header files uses conditional compilation (e.g. the preprocessor directives `#if`, `#ifdef` or `#ifndef`) for those declarations. If they do, then add a `#define` (or `#undef`) before the specific header file is included so the definition will not be part of the translation unit.

Comment: As your suggestion, I edited it just now, this may not work here.

Comment: This could be changed in ACE, probably by adding a ACE_LACKS_PID_T define which you can undefine in your config.h

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug in ACE, it is a workaround for the lack of this type in the Windows SDK. It looks different products have different workarounds which could cause conflicts. ACE 6.2.9 will use ACE_LACKS_PID_T which you can undefine in your ace/config.h file.

Comment: We have released today ACE 6.3.0 which has the support for undefining ACE_LACKS_PID_T which then disables the typdef of pid_t by ACE.